# Populate table in jsp using DTO using spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm having issues filling out a table in my jsp with a list array of objects.  I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong as everywhere I look it's telling me to do it the way I have it.

Here is my jsp table:

```
<table id="budgetTbl" action="" method="post" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Budget</th>
            <th>Projected</th>
            <th>Actual</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="budget" items="${budgets}">
            <tr>
                <td>${budget.budgetName}</td>
                <td>${budget.budgetAmount}</td>
                <td>${budget.actual}</td>
            </tr>       
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the code in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="budget" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getBudget(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {

    List<Budget> budgets = budgetService.getBudgets(1);

    model.addAttribute("budgets", budgets);

    if(user.getLoggedIn())
        return "budget";
    else
        return "redirect:login.html";

}
```

My bean:

```
<jsp:useBean id="budget" class="com.lindeman.model.Budget"/>        
<jsp:setProperty name="budget" property="*"/>
```

budgetService:

```
@Service("budgetService")
public class BudgetServiceImpl implements BudgetService {

public List<Budget> getBudgets(int dateID) {

    List<Budget> budgets = new ArrayList<Budget>();


    try (CachedRowSet bud = DAO.getAllBudgets(dateID)) {

        bud.beforeFirst();
        while(bud.next()){

            Budget budget = new Budget();

            budget.setBudgetID(bud.getInt("BudgetID"));             
            budget.setDateID(bud.getInt("DateID"));             
            budget.setBudgetName(bud.getString("BudgetName"));              
            budget.setBudgetAmount(bud.getDouble("BudgetAmount"));              
            budget.setActual(bud.getDouble("Actual"));

            budgets.add(budget);

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        DataDriver.processException(e);
    }


    return budgets;

}

}
```

Comment: It's not displaying anything in my table.  I've verified that the list has values in it, but it won't show in the table.

Comment: Just to verify the code, can you try adding attribute to `HttpSession`?

Comment: Ok, so I realized I forgot to have my bean at the top of my jsp, but now now it's only displaying the object in my arraylist.  Do I have my foreach loop setup wrong?

Comment: loop seems to be fine, probably EL is not evaluated, may be its ignored in the jsp.

Comment: I've added my bean as that was the issue to begin with, is something there wrong?  It's only retrieving the last budget object in the arraylist.

Comment: What is inside `budgetService.getBudgets(1);` ?

Comment: Added that to main post

Comment: it seems that there is only one budget for date id 1, do verify your data in db and the select query

Comment: There are three, and I've verified that there are 3 budget objects in the budgets arraylist.

Comment: Kindly remove the `jsp:useBean` and `jsp:setProperty` tag from the jsp, it creates a new object of budget available in the page scope.

Comment: Without that in there, it doesn't even create the one row.

Comment: Let me clarify, using `jsp:useBean` you are creating a new budget in the jsp itself, it is not the budget what you hope may be retrieved from db.

Comment: Do try setting attribute to the session i.e. `budgets` instead of model.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, which would be why the last one would come in the table that way as it was the last created budget object.  Any thoughts on why I'm not able to access the budget objects?  If I just put ${budgets} it does show all three objects. Oh, and thank you so much for your help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the taglib import, put it on the top of the jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```